# How old was Luke Skywalker when he finally died?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, luke-skywalker

Within the Star Wars universe, **is there any description of how Luke Skywalker dies and his age when it happened?**

Answers from either the Star Wars main canon (e.g. films, TV shows) *or* the Expanded Universe canon (e.g. books, comics, games, etc ) will be acceptable.

Comment: We don't have a canon answer for this and we won't until the sequel trilogy is released (assuming that answers it).

Comment: @DarthSatan - Agreed. I'm tempted to close as "opinion-based"

Comment: For anyone wondering why Richard would choose "opinion-based", see [Should questions about future works be closed as Primarily Opinion Based?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5184)

Comment: Currently in the Legends canon, where he *has* died, no date of death has been firmly established.

Comment: So why not answer it in the canon it is answerable in? (Being _Legends_). I have too little knowledge of any _Star Wars_ EU, but an answer that read, "in _Legends_, blah blah blah, while in main canon, he hasn't died (yet), but we'll have to wait for the movies to come out", wouldn't be opinion based.

Comment: I don't really see it as intentionally opinion based, just more of a mistake assuming that his death had occurred yet.

Comment: @SQB - I agree. I've reworded it to include a reference to EU canon, making it no longer purely opinion-based.

Answer (score 10):

Within the authorised Star Wars canon, Luke's death has not been described. Based on unconfirmed rumours, Luke may die in the upcoming Star Wars <s>VII</s> VIII film, but obviously only time will tell on that one.

---

Within the Legends EU canon, Luke Skywalker's death hasn't been described in any great detail. The best information we have suggests that his death occurred sometime between 45ABY and 137ABY.

This is based on his appearance in the [Star Wars : Fate of the Jedi : Apocalypse](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fate_of_the_Jedi:_Apocalypse) book (set in 45ABY) and his appearance as a force ghost in the [Star Wars : Legacy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Legacy) comics (set in 137ABY).

Comment: Should it be closer to the latter date? I thought one could only remain a force ghost for a limited period of time...

Comment: @michael - Not as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Michael The Sith on Korriban managed to manifest themselves after millennia as force ghosts, as did for example Exar Kun on Yavin 4. It was however not only Sith that managed this, since Exar Kun's Jedi Master Vodo-Siosk Baas joined Luke and his first students in the final battle against Kun. So even if there *were* a time limit, it would have to be at least 4000 years, which is much longer than the less than a century timespan considered here.

Comment: On Wookiepedia about the [Legacy Era](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_era), there is the following comment about Luke's death: "*In the hole between the Fate of the Jedi book series and the Star Wars: Legacy comics, there are lots of **unanswered questions**: the downfall, redemption and return of the New Jedi Order, and **the ultimate fates of characters such as Luke Skywalker**, Leia Organa Solo, Han Solo, Ben Skywalker, Jaina Solo Fel, R2-D2, C-3PO, and others.*"

Comment: And on Wookiepedia's [Luke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker) page, his death is listed as "*Between 45 ABY and 137 ABY*".  So his death had not been established yet in the Legends EU (not counting the appearance of his Force ghost in the Legacy comics) when Disney acquired Star Wars.

Comment: Though Luke *did* recently die in a video clip from "Star Wars: Battlefront": [Luke Skywalker Crushed To Death In ‘Star Wars’ Video Game: Watch Shocking Video](http://hollywoodlife.com/2015/10/10/luke-skywalker-star-wars-battlefront-dies-video/)

Comment: Luke didn't die in Force Awakens